# Incoming Call iOS

Tags: ios, swift3

Is there anyway to send myself an email when a cellular call is incoming on my iPhone? Is it possible that this app could run in the background as well?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the Apple documentation for [CallKit](https://developer.apple.com/reference/callkit) Using some of the functionality there, you might be able to achieve what you want.

I don't believe you can use the answer call functionality since that is for VOIP, but you might be able to use the call blocking functionality to do what you wanted. Since I have not implemented something along those lines, I can't tell you for sure if that would work or not.

But do note that you never get any number information since that could lead to privacy violations. So at best, all you'd get would an e-mail saying that a call was coming in (maybe) but not who called.